# I'm Gone Before You Know It. What Am I?

Tags: riddle, mathematics

Here's a crazy riddle for you.
Figure out what I am, if you can:

> I'm gone before you know it, 
>   yet I go on and on and on...

Can you tell me what I am?

Comment: Seems like a "Erpheevat qrpvzny"(rot13)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Pi/pie

I'm gone before you know it, yet I go on and on and on...

> People love pie and eat it quickly, and pi is irrational, so its decimal places never repeat and go on infinitely.

Comment: Yep!  That's it.  You got every part of the puzzle--good job!  :)

Comment: Life would be so much simpler and happier if the one that went on and on was the other one, and vice versa :-)

Comment: Definitely! :-p

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Infinity?

I'm gone before you know it, yet I go on and on and on...

> There's the old joke that when you count to infinity, add one, and you still won't reach infinity. Infinity is endless.
> Of course, Chuck Norris did manage to count to infinity twice...

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you could be a

> Missed train :)

Comment: Wasn't what I'd thought about originally, and not math-related per se, but creative--nice!